# Print array results in a figure eight pattern

Tags: java, arrays, console

I have results from an array and I want to print them in a figure eight and below is the code that does this:

```
tempString2 = "\t" + trainTrack[5]+ "\n" + trainTrack[4] + "\t\t"
+ trainTrack[6] + "\n"+ trainTrack[3] + "\t\t" + trainTrack[7]+ "\n"
+ trainTrack[2] + "\t\t" + trainTrack[8]  + "\n"+ trainTrack[1]  + "\t\t"
+ trainTrack[9]  + "\n\t" + trainTrack[0]  + "\n"+ trainTrack[10] + "\t\t"
+ trainTrack[18] + "\n" + trainTrack[11] + "\t\t" + trainTrack[17] + "\n"
+ trainTrack[12] + "\t\t" + trainTrack[16] + "\n"+ trainTrack[13] + "\t\t"
+ trainTrack[15] + "\n\t" + trainTrack[14];
```

and below is what is shown when I output the string:

```
      [..]
[..]        [..]
[..]        [..]
[..]        [..]
[..]        [..]
      [..]
[..]        [..]
[..]        [..]
[..]        [..]
[..]        [..]
      [..]
```

but is there a way of making it more presentable, with rounder edges so it actually looks like an eight?

Comment: how do I do that, I don't know what they are! Can you provide an example

Comment: Do you want suggestions of other symbols to use, other ways of presenting the eight as text or solutions for showing it graphically?

Comment: well if you could show me an example of how to do this I would be able to create the pattern myself but I just need guidance on the matter

Comment: I have provided a possible pattern. Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly the answer you want, but you could try this:

```
tempString2 = "      " + trainTrack[5]+ "\n  " + trainTrack[4] + "    " + trainTrack[6]
    + "\n"+ trainTrack[3] + "        " + trainTrack[7]  + "\n"+ trainTrack[2] + "        "
    + trainTrack[8] + "\n  "+ trainTrack[1] + "    " + trainTrack[9] + "\n      "
    + trainTrack[0] + "\n  "+ trainTrack[10] + "    " + trainTrack[18] + "\n"+ trainTrack[11]
    + "        " + trainTrack[17]   + "\n"+ trainTrack[12] + "        " + trainTrack[16]
    + "\n  "+ trainTrack[13] + "    " + trainTrack[15] + "\n      " + trainTrack[14];
```

Output:

```
      [..]
  [..]    [..]
[..]        [..]
[..]        [..]
  [..]    [..]
      [..]
  [..]    [..]
[..]        [..]
[..]        [..]
  [..]    [..]
      [..]
```

You can also achieve the same result with [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29). It makes a smaller, neater, but less understandable program:

```
String tempString2 = String.format("%10s\n%6s%8s\n%4s%12s\n%4s%12s\n%6s%8s\n%10s\n%6s%8s\n%4s%12s\n%4s%12s\n%6s%8s\n%10s",
    trainTrack[5], trainTrack[4], trainTrack[6], trainTrack[3], trainTrack[7], trainTrack[2],
    trainTrack[8], trainTrack[1], trainTrack[9], trainTrack[0], trainTrack[10],
    trainTrack[18], trainTrack[11], trainTrack[17], trainTrack[12], trainTrack[16],
    trainTrack[13], trainTrack[15], trainTrack[14]);
```

Comment: this answer is correct but very unconventional! I thought there might have been some method that accepted so distance parameters or something like that!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
  [..][..]
[..]    [..]
[..]    [..]
[..]    [..]
[..][..][..]
[..]    [..]
[..]    [..]
[..]    [..]
  [..][..]
```

Looks cleaner and more appropriate. (and rounder too)

Comment: I can't do that because that is not the desired output, I need to have it as described in the question! So is there any way of doing this?

Comment: I have changed the answer. Check it out.

Comment: yes that is a better answer but I still need it to display as suggested in the question! I know i have used tab but is there a way of specifying the exact space that the objects are moved so I could set them individually?

Comment: Yes. Instead of "\t", enter "   " with the required number of spaces in the quotes.